# Hide/Show route layer in Leaflet when click on button (Easy Button plugin)

Tags: leaflet, jquery

I have a Leaflet map with button (Easy Button plugin https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton). When click on button on map added route layer (plugin https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine). Please, help me add event for button to show/hide layer when I click on button. Map example:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [50.0669, 35.1638],
    zoom: 15
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '&copy; Map Data <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


L.easyButton('fa-level-up',
    function() {

        var routing = L.Routing.control({
            plan: L.Routing.plan([
                L.latLng(50.07132, 35.14103),
                L.latLng(50.05459, 35.18239)
            ], {
                waypointIcon: function(i) {
                    return new L.Icon.Label.Default({
                        labelText: String.fromCharCode(65 + i)
                    });
                },
                geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim()
            }),
            routeWhileDragging: true,
            routeDragTimeout: 250
        });

var rlayer = L.layerGroup([routing]);
map.hasLayer(rlayer) ? map.removeLayer(rlayer) : map.addLayer(rlayer);      

},
    'Display Route'
).addTo(map);
```

I try use map.hasLayer(rlayer) ? map.removeLayer(rlayer) : map.addLayer(rlayer); but route layer after second click don't hide

Comment: I tried to put it on my map but when I click on the button, the console tells me 2 errors : - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the variable `rlayer` outside of the easybutton function. Try that:

```
var rlayer = null;

L.easyButton('fa-level-up',

  function() {

    if (rlayer) {
      map.removeLayer(rlayer);
      rlayer = null;
    } else {
      var routing = L.Routing.control(...);
      rlayer = L.layerGroup([routing]);
      map.addLayer(rlayer);
    }

  }, 'Display Route').addTo(map);
```