# Leaflet display only clicked element of a loaded map layer (polyline)

Tags: leaflet, carto, geojson, jquery, carto-js

I am creating a web mapping application that will return appropriate routes based upon ST_length query on a cartoDB dataset. So far, the code below successfully maps those routes with individual colours and clears any others that may have previously been selected:

```
<script>
var myRoutes = null;

var sqlQueryOne = "SELECT *, ST_length(the_geom::geography)/1000 as length FROM my_routes WHERE ST_length(the_geom::geography)/1000 <=5";

// A function to set individual colours based on length
var determineColor = function(length) { // etc....

// Function to add all routes less than 5km
function showFive(){

//Remove any previously selected routes
    if(map.hasLayer(myRoutes)){
        map.removeLayer(myRoutes);
        };

// Get the data from db in geoJSON and using previously defined query
    $.getJSON("https://"+cartoDBUserName+".cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q="+sqlQueryOne, function(data) {
        myRoutes = L.geoJson(data,{
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup('<h2><p>' + feature.properties.name + '</h2>' + '<p><b>KiLR Rating</b><br />' + feature.properties.ratings + '</p><em>' + feature.properties.highlights + '</em><br />' + '<p>' + '<b>' + feature.properties.length + "km" + '</b></p>');
                layer.cartodb_id=feature.properties.cartodb_id;
                layer.setStyle({
                   color: determineColor(feature.properties.length)
                   })
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    });         
};
```

You can see that each route has a pop-up.  What I would like to do is unload the other routes when an individual route is clicked (and keep the pop-up) so a user can more clearly see where the route actually goes (note some overlap in the routes).
[image]

Update: I now have what I think should be a working block to highlight the clicked route only from the layer.

This will style the clicked layer:

```
layer.setStyle({opacity: 1, width: 3, color: 'red'});
```

However I need some help implementing something to style the clicked and not clicked routes:

```
layer.on('click', function (e) {
    e.target.feature.properties.selected = true;
       layer.setStyle({
       color: highlightRoute(e.target.feature.properties.selected)});
    });
```

I appear to have lost the plot on writing the highlightRoute bit.  So far (and I know this is not correct but don't know how to fix) I have:

```
    var highlightRoute = function (ml) {
        if (e.target.feature.properties.selected == true) {
            return 'red';
        } else {
            return 'gainsboro';
        }
    };
```

Can anyone help sort this little niggle out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `show()` (the sublayer you have clicked on) or `hide()` (the rest of the sublayers) methods as explained [in this tutorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view/#toggling-functions).

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't clear to me how I can use this method without re-writing my entire code.  I'm not creating a layer from a visualisation I have published I am using the SQL API to call polylines from the dataset.  From what I can see the syntax is totally different.  Perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it carefully. In addition to the post you suggested at the end of your question, there is [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130948/hide-show-route-layer-in-leaflet-when-click-on-button-easy-button-plugin) that can help you. Similar to the methods I cited, you can set a variable/layer for each route using the SQL API and then use `removeLayer()` and `addLayer()` Leaflet methods.

Comment: Sorry, still not following this method!  Ideally, I don't want to have each route returned as an individual layer.  I am trying to load route options in together, then the user picks the one they want to do based on how it looks and the pop-up info.  When the user has decided they click on the route line they want and this is on the only one left on the map.  I am trying to implement within the `myRoutes = L.geoJSON(data` section by implementing a `layer.on('click', function ()` as per the post linked at the end of my question but this hasn't been successful.